# list all factor levels of a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

with `str(data)` I get the `head`of the levels (1-2 values)

```
fac1: Factor w/ 2  levels ... :
fac2: Factor w/ 5  levels ... :
fac3: Factor w/ 20 levels ... :
val: num ...
```

with `dplyr::glimpse(data)` I get more values, but no infos about number/values of factor-levels. Is there an automatic way to get all level informations of all factor vars in a data.frame? A short form with more info for

```
levels(data$fac1)
levels(data$fac2)
levels(data$fac3)
```

or more precisely a elegant version for something like

```
for (n in names(data))
  if (is.factor(data[[n]])) {
    print(n)
    print(levels(data[[n]]))
  }
```

thx
Christof

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here are some options.  We loop through the 'data' with `sapply` and get the `levels` of each column (assuming that all the columns are `factor` class)

```
sapply(data, levels)
```

Or if we need to pipe (`%>%`) it, this can be done as

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     sapply(levels)
```

Or another option is `summarise_each` from `dplyr` where we specify the `levels` within the `funs`.

```
 data %>%
      summarise_each(funs(list(levels(.))))
```

Comment: How do we get length of all of those levels

Comment: @BigDataScientist check my answer

Answer (score 9):

If your problem is specifically to output a list of all levels for a factor, then I have found a simple solution using :

> unique(df$x)

For instance, for the infamous iris dataset:

> unique(iris$Species)

Answer (score 6):

Or using purrr:

```
data %>% purrr::map(levels)
```

Or to first factorize everything:

```
data %>% dplyr::mutate_all(as.factor) %>% purrr::map(levels)
```

And answering the question about how to get the lengths:

```
data %>% map(levels) %>% map(length)
```

Comment: Nice approach. I like it.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler method is to use the sqldf package and use a select distinct statement. This makes it easier to automatically get the names of factor levels and then specify as levels to other columns/variables.

Generic code snippet is:

```
library(sqldf)
    array_name = sqldf("select DISTINCT *colname1* as '*column_title*' from *table_name*")
```

Sample code using iris dataset:

```
df1 = iris
factor1 <- sqldf("select distinct Species as 'flower_type' from df1")
factor1    ## to print the names of factors
```

Output:

```
  flower_type
1      setosa
2  versicolor
3   virginica
```

Comment: If you indent each code line by 4 spaces it will format itself properly.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to display factor levels only for thos columns which are declared `as.factor`, you can use:

```
lapply(df[sapply(df, is.factor)], levels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate option to get length of levels in a 'data'.frame:

```
data_levels_length <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(data)), function(x){
  length(levels(data[,x]))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As a long data frame (tibble):

```r
df %>% gather(name, value) %>% count(name, value)
```

This converts all the columns into name-value pairs, and then counts the unique levels.

Subset column types with something like:

```r
df %>% select_if(is.character) %>% ...
```

Via https://stackoverflow.com/a/47122651/3217870

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr) #for all the following

df$factor %>% unique() %>% str()
```

lists and counts the frequency of levels of a specific variable

```
count(df,variable)
```

returns a table with the levels of a specific variable and its frequency.
the number of rows will inform how many levels there are for this variable.

```
count(df,across())
```

returns a table of all variables levels that co-occur in observations and the frequency of all different combinations